# SQL Server Application Roles and server level permissions

Tags: sql-server

Has anyone come up with a way to view server state (or similar) while using an Applicaition Role, or - failing that of calling sp_SetAppRole & sp_UnSetAppRole from within a stored procedure?

sp_SetAppRole and sp_UnSetAppRole cause an error ...Ad hoc only... when called from within an sp - and their code cannot be reused elsewhere

It is not possible to grant VIEW SERVER STATE to an entity that does not exist at Server level or in the Master Database (Application roles exist only in their own db)

Comment: Did you try BEGIN TRY/END TRY and BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH?

Comment: afraid that'll just lets you handle the exception - there's a work around using a certificate created in the Role's home database being backed up and restored to the master database (where the server state data lives) that looks solid - its ugly but allows proper granular access - which seems my best bet unless someone has something more graceful